# Ignore_user_abort php simil in Django/python?

Tags: python, django

Somebody know how set this behavior in Django/python? I need send an Ajax request and keep it living if the user close the page

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior already ? I can't see why the request would stop before finishing when the user close the page. I didn't try it so I can't swear, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Nop, isn't the default behavior, I have an ajax script that fire a downloader script in the server side, if the user close the page the script don't download the images, but if i let the ajax finish then all works fine

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use something like this :
http://celeryproject.org/
Or simply execute script in separate thread like this:
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/path/to/script.py'])

Comment: So in `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/path/to/script.py'])`, django's equivalent of `ignore_user_abort` is set to On ?